# String matching this lookaround regex

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I am studying regex lookaround from [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) tutorial.

It has an example explaining how lookaround are used to check the existence (or non-existence), but the regex inside lookaround parentheses is not used for actual match.

In example, the pattern `q(?=u)i` is checked against String **quit**. And it doesn't return a match.

I understood the example.
But I can't think of any string that matches this regex pattern. If my understanding of lookaround is correct I think there isn't any String that matches with this regex.

Am I correct? If not, which String matches this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of this tutorial site, but if you read closely what it actually says, it never claims that the regex `q(?=u)i` matches the string `quit`:

> Let's take one more look inside, to make sure you understand the implications of the lookahead. Let's apply q(?=u)i to quit. The lookahead is now positive and is followed by another token. Again, q matches q and u matches u. **Again, the match from the lookahead must be discarded, so the engine steps back from i in the string to u.** The lookahead was successful, so the engine continues with i. But i cannot match u. So this match attempt fails. All remaining attempts fail as well, because there are no more q's in the string.

I think you might still be confused about how lookaheads work.  Either that, or you misread the tutorial site.  If the former, then lookaheads work by *asserting* a match, without actually *consuming* anything in the string.  So the regex `q(?=u)i` says to:

```
match the letter 'q'
lookahead to the next character after 'q' and assert that it is 'u'
then match an 'i' immediately after the 'q'
```

Of course, the string 'quit' fails, and in fact all strings would fail.  The lookahead says to verify that `q` is followed by `u`, but the following pattern contradicts this by insisting that `i` is what follows.

Comment: I follow you and I think my language was a little confusing. I've changed question a bit to make things more clear. I'm looking for a string that returns a match on `q(?=u)i`. **quit** doesn't return a match. I could not think of a string that will return a match against this regex.

Comment: @gitblame I don't think you followed what I said actually.  There is _no_ string which will match this regex.  Again, the lookahead asserts `qu` while the actual pattern matches `qi`.  Obviously, this will always fail for any string.

Comment: didn't read last statement of your answer earlier. Understood it now. Thanks.

Comment: @gitblame Lookarounds are possibly the highest barrier of entry to mastering regex, so you can expect for it to take a while to click.